# Bootstrap Formatting in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Bootstrap website displays correctly in all browsers besides Internet Explorer. Basically I want my 'Lot boxes' to always be formatted the same way with the image on the left and the information on the right but at certain sizes in IE it puts the text below the image. You can see it in action here: http://timtroiano.com/chalk/

Here is the code for my lot boxes:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
       print '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"><div class="img">
            <a class="img" href="rowforURL" data-lightbox="set" data-title="infoForLightbox">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="rowForURL" alt=""/>
            </a>
            <div class="desc">';

            print 'FirstLineOfText</br>
            SecondLine</br>
            ThirdLine</br>
            FourthLine</br>
            FifthLine'</div>
            </div></div>';
    }
```

And here is the css code for the div img class and the div desc class:

```
div.img {
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    height: auto;
    width: 304;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

div.desc {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 180px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: My best guess is that it's your invalid `width: 304;` declaration that's causing it in IE 9. IE10 and 11 behaves as expected when resizing the window. Possibly try adding `display: -ms-flexbox;` and `-ms-flex-direction: row;` too? Good luck.

Comment: You're a savior! That worked great, thank you. I can't wait for the day when we don't have to design for compatibility in IE.

Comment: Me too! Glad to have helped you figure it out.